# How to find the corresponding ES query for a Chewy query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, rubygems, chewy-gem

I use use `chewy` in my rails app to query ElasticSearch.

`Autocomplete` is my ElasticSearch Index.

```
AutocompleteIndex.suggest(
      suggest: {
        text: cleanup_query('query'),
        completion: {
          field: 'search_suggest',
          size: 10,
          contexts: {
            entity: @contexts
          },
          fuzzy: { fuzziness: 'AUTO' }
        }
      }
    ).suggest
```

this is the chewy query I use to query `Autocomplete` data.
This, in turn, queries like this,

```
{:body=>{:suggest=>{:suggest=>{:text=>["9"], :completion=>{:field=>"search_suggest", :size=>10, :contexts=>{:entity=>[{:context=>"All"}]}, :fuzzy=>{:fuzziness=>"AUTO"}}}}}, :index=>["autocomplete"], :type=>[]}
```

How can I get the corresponding ElasticSearch Query for the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable ES log, set `Chewy.logger.level = :debug` in initializers/chewy.rb

```
{:body=>{:suggest=>{:suggest=>{:text=>["9"], :completion=>{:field=>"search_suggest", :size=>10, :contexts=>{:entity=>[{:context=>"All"}]}, :fuzzy=>{:fuzziness=>"AUTO"}}}}}, :index=>["autocomplete"], :type=>[]}
```

The above is the formatted elastic search query. The corresponding ES query for the above would be:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/autocomplete/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
        "suggest" : {
            "suggest" : {
                "text" : ["9"],
                "completion": {
                    "field": "search_suggest",
                    "size": 10,
                    "contexts": {
                        "entity":[{"context": "All"}]
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
}
'
```